# How Windows Host can access Guest OS by name

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualization, virtualbox

The host OS is Windows, Guest OS is Linux running on VirtualBox.  I setup Network and can access the Guest OS from the Host by IP address.  Let's say this is IP 192.168.22.10.  This part makes sense to me.

Now I modified the Guest OS /etc/hosts file and assigned a name to the guest, say guestvm, which is mapped to the IP address of the Guest OS so 192.168.22.10 => guestvm.  Now in the Guest OS, I can access the guest machine by localhost, or by guestvm.  All Good so far,

When I ping guestvm from the Host OS (Windows), It takes a bit, but then somehow Windows does find guestvm.local is equivalent to 192.168.22.10 and is able to access the Guest OS.  I did not make any IP changes on the Host, Windows, side at all.  So how can The host map guestvm to ip 192.168.22.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a mechanism such as [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS).